# Prevent Uniqe Text in jQuery Autocomplete

Tags: jquery, autocomplete

I'm working on a project where I need a jQuery auto-complete for Cities.  What I don't want is for someone to enter in a unique city name and have it ball up my system.

I need to be able to CLEAR the input if someone types it in incorrectly and FORCE them to use the list I give them.

I can get the dropdown working properly using the [jQuery AutoComplete](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Autocomplete), but I just cant figure out how to customize it for preventing invalid data from being inserted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

after searching the forums, I found a link to the [options](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Autocomplete/autocomplete#toptions) page where there is a `mustMatch` parameter.  This looks like it might be what I'm looking for, so I'll give it a try.